# Changing the font in XScreensaver's dialogs?

Tags: elementary-os, xscreensaver

I decided to build XScreensaver from source recently after realizing my distribution had a slightly outdated build in the repo. Everything is great except for the dialog boxes, which have a humungous, awful, Papyrus like font.

I'm told that I can edit a file titled ".Xdefaults", but that file doesn't exist. Nor does .Xresources, which supposedly does the same thing. Apparently if I don't have one that I need to create it myself. But if one doesn't exist, then where is the program getting this font from? I feel like creating an .Xdefaults file wouldn't solve the problem here. I tried editing the source code to change the font but it seems like the program just ignores any changes I make to the font names and keeps the font.

[image: Awful font]

I'm using Elementary OS. I'm told xscreensaver doesn't work well with eOS, but since the version I downloaded from the package manager has a different font, I beg to differ.

Answer (score 1):

X resources come from several places; the first place is the database inside the X server and managed with, e.g., `xrdb`. Typically `~/.Xresources` (if it exists) will be loaded into the X server by your distro's X login scripts — using `xrdb`. `~/.Xdefaults` servers a similar purpose.

The fallback (before compiled-in defaults) is the app defaults files. I'm not entirely sure where they're located on Elementary OS, but on Debian they're in `/etc/X11/app-defaults` — in particular, take a look at `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XScreenSaver`. Another possible location is `/usr/lib/X11/app-defaults/XScreenSaver`.

BTW: XScreenSaver probably uses traditional X font naming, not modern Fontconfig naming. Which also may mean not all fonts are available. `xfontsel` can be used to get the traditional X font name (and find a font you like).